# GCM push notifications are not working in tablet

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on GCM Push notifications for my application. The GCM push notifications are working fine in Android 4.0.4  OS devices, but in HCL ME U1 tablet, they are not working. In that HCL tablet, playstore is also not working properly. Is it because of playstore that GCM push notifications are not working in the tablet?.

Can any one guide me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Does the device has the Google Services Framework ?

Comment: Thanks for ur replay.The tablet has only Google playstore app.

Comment: whenever i open the playstore app,immediately it closes.

Comment: playstore also not working properly means? is there an account configured? is tablet successfully able to register?

Comment: @con_9 thanks for ur replay.Google account is configured in the tablet.

Comment: ok, when u request to register from tablet, do u get a valid registration id?

Comment: aren't you [brett lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brett_Lee). You are popular man..... :D

Comment: Successfully configured the google account in that tablet.But GCM push notifications are not working.

Comment: @con_9 getting registration id empty from GCM server.

Comment: Any one help me out from this issue?

Comment: @Vishwas Sharma i am not an cricketer man...

Comment: il post the code to register

Comment: @brettlee ya, I know. It was just a little humour. I apologize if you didn't like it.

Comment: @con_9 thanks again.Please post code.

Comment: @VishwasSharma No problem, help me if you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: @brettlee why not. In fact right now, I am doing research on your question.

Answer (score 0):

make sure u register this way and ur sender id is correct. Then you would recve a call to `public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` overridden method of your class extending intentservice class. 
So what you should look at is, the error message that you get using `intent.getStringExtra("error");` here intent object is you got in `onHandleIntent` method.This will tell you why google cudnt register your device.

```
try {
            GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
            //String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            //String regId = sharedPrefs.getString(myRegKey, "");
            //if(regId.equals(""))
            {
                Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
                registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", Your sender id here);
                startService(registrationIntent);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Edit1**

```
@Override
        public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            try {
                    String action = intent.getAction();
                    if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                        handleRegistration(intent);
                    } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                        onMessage(this, intent);
                    }
               } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
               } 
        }
protected void handleRegistration(Intent intent) {
        String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
        String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra("unregistered");  
//rest of code
}
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
//rest of code
}
```

Can you tell me the values of registrationId, error, unregistered ?

Comment: override onHandleIntent method and use intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");

Comment: hi con_9, i tried ur code, but iam getting the value of  intent.getStringExtra("error") as  NULL.

Comment: can u post ur onHandleIntent method?

Comment: //GCMIntentService                                                                                                        public class GCMIntentService extends IntentService {
 public GCMIntentService() {
  super(SENDER_ID);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
  Log.d("error...", error);}}

Comment: see my Edit1, and tell me the values of registrationId, error, unregistered.

Comment: I am getting the error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at this line  GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

Comment: GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
                Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
                registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
                registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", SENDER_ID);
                startService(registrationIntent);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

Comment: Can u help me to fix this issue?

Comment: in my HCL tablet, playstore is not working, when i  open the playstore immediately closes.Bcoz of that issue, GCM registraition is not working in my device.But in my emulator GCM is working.

Comment: Hi,iam successfully register my emulator with GCM server and getting deviceID.But, when i push messages from dotnet server,getting Error:Missing Registration.Can any one help me?